# aws cloudsearch/lucene query street names

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, amazon-cloudsearch

I uploaded a dataset of addresses to AWS cloudsearch and would need to be able to query the street names in a flexible way:

dataset value:
{ street: "Michael-Bayerhammer-Strasse" }

All of the following queries should result in a match:
Michael-Gundringer-Strasse
Michael-Gundringerstr. 
Michael-Gundringer-Str.
Michael-GundringerStr.
etc.

I could not find a way to achieve this. Is there a way to do this with cloudsearch/lucene or any other tools?

You can test it with my cloudsearch url:

This returns the expected results:

http://search-geocode-austria-irx6qepcnpnb2gp4lp5tz37tky.eu-west-1.cloudsearch.amazonaws.com/2013-01-01/search?q=Michael-Gundringer-Strasse

This does not find any matches:

http://search-geocode-austria-irx6qepcnpnb2gp4lp5tz37tky.eu-west-1.cloudsearch.amazonaws.com/2013-01-01/search?q=Michael-Gundringerstr.

EDIT:
Ok I figures out how to deal with some of the possible queries:
replace - with space and . with *

This produces results for:

Michael-Gundringer-Strasse
Michael-Gundringer-Str.

but I am still struggling with Michael-Gundringerstr. Is there a way to only require a partial match from lucene (i.e. that it matchesa database entry with Gundringer a query of Gundringerstr)?

Comment: I did not get result in any of the above mentioned urls

Comment: @Richa sry. copy paste mistake. this first one should now work

Comment: As per your question your dataset is `Michael-Bayerhammer-Strasse`. But after hitting first url none of the documents contain that street name. My another question: What is the mapping of `street `

Comment: @Richa That was by mistake. I changed the query to Michael-Gundringer-Strasse

Comment: What about mapping of `street`. Is it analysed or not?

Answer (score 1):

I see two problems to solve:

### Tokenizing the Address

You need the address to be broken up into the proper tokens and you have a few different formats to deal with.

**Dash-delimited:** CloudSearch will tokenize on punctuation, so something like Michael-Gundringer-Str will be broken into '*Michael*' '*Gundringer*' and '*Str*'. No problem there.

**Case-delimited:** CS does not tokenize camel-cased strings, so you would need to break up *GundringerStr* yourself (easy enough regex).

**Undelimited:** you have *Gundringerstr*  -- I don't think there's any way to tokenize this other than writing some hard-coded rules, which may be feasible depending on the data.

See the docs for more about [text processing](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudsearch/latest/developerguide/text-processing.html) and tokenization.

### Treating Str and Strasse as Equivalent

You want *strasse* to match *str*. You can do this by configuring a custom list of synonyms. See the [docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudsearch/latest/developerguide/configuring-analysis-schemes.html#synonyms) for more. You may also be able to accomplish this through *algorithmic stemming*, where CS internally would stem *strasse* and store it as *str*. You could turn on full algorithmic stemming and test it out (the default for German is light stemming).

Comment: I have now managed to tokenize it the following way:
replace all "-" and "." with "* ". So Michael-Gundringer-Str. becomes Michael* Gundringer* Str* ... This covers most cases except for Michael-Gundringerstr. (as you have mentioned). I will now try to add a second street field (e.g. streetcompressed) and have it remove the last special character in the street name --> Michael-GundringerStrasse. This will then allow me to match with Michael-Gundringerstr. It is not ideal since I have to introduce an extra field but it seems to be the only way since there is nothing like a "partial" match.

Comment: If the compressed form is always just the first few letters of the uncompressed form, you could just append `*` to your query term. That wouldn't work at all in English but maybe Germans have fewer and less irregular ways of abbreviating words for streets.

Comment: Side-Note: `Str => Strasse` is easier to setup as synonym than stemming i think.

Answer (score 0):

If `street` field is `analysed` you can get that done using `query_string`

```
GET /index1/type1/_search
{
"query": {
    "query_string": {
       "default_field": "street",
       "query": "Michael-Bayerhammer Str"
    }
   }
}
```

Comment: is this for elasticsearch? can I also use it with aws cloudsearch? could you show me how to write it as a URL (see my edited question for details)